# Filtering nested lists according to the absolute minimum in python

Tags: python, list

Within each list of lists, I want to keep only the list whose second element is the absolute minimum among all the second elements.

Without success, I've tried to use a list comprehension with `filter` and `min(lst,key=abs)`.

Here is an example with three list of lists:

```
input_list = [[[0, -5, 'rising']], 
[[0, -5, 'boost'], [0, -2, 'rise'], [0, -1, 'increase']],
[[1, -2, 'decrease'], [0, -3, 'lower']]]
```

For instance, the second list of lists is composed of three lists and the absolute minimum among the second element of each of these lists is -1, so out of this list of lists I want to only keep `[0, -1, 'increase']`.

Here is the desired output :

```
output_list = [[0, -5, 'rising'], 
[0, -1, 'increase'], 
[0, -2, 'decrease']]
```

Comment: Shouldn't be the last element of output `[1, -2, 'decrease']` ?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thanks for spotting that mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `sorted` to get the minimum:

```
>>> output_list = [sorted(inner_list, key=lambda x:abs(x[1]))[0]
                   for inner_list in input_list]

>>> output_list
[[0, -5, 'rising'], [0, -1, 'increase'], [1, -2, 'decrease']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension with `min()` function and custom `key=`

```
input_list = [[[0, -5, 'rising']],
[[0, -5, 'boost'], [0, -2, 'rise'], [0, -1, 'increase']],
[[1, -2, 'decrease'], [0, -3, 'lower']]]

out = [min(l, key=lambda k: abs(k[1])) for l in input_list]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[[0, -5, 'rising'], [0, -1, 'increase'], [1, -2, 'decrease']]
```